# Selective concatenation of two huge files

Tags: python

I have two really huge flat text files (> 10 GB each). The files consist with many lines - each line is a string (about 80 bytes) the separatorn and then another bigger string.
The first string like a unique key for the first file but can be repeated in second file.
So, I need get a result files - and it should contain key (may be duplicated like in second file) the separator the second string from first file and then second string from second file.

I'm thinking to use dict to store info from 1-st file: key = someHash(str1), value = position in file and the iterate via second file and print result to third file
But I'do not know which hash should be used and if should be used at all
And how resolve possible collision?
And finally how build effective (memory + time) solution for this problem

Comment: That's a join of two tables in database terms. How about using a database for it?

Comment: Using in-memory dictionary could possibly eat more memory then input files have. So unless you have 16GB or more to spare I would recommend using sqlite database as a intermediary to merge the log files.

Comment: Are the lines in the files ordered? How many records do you have?

Comment: If the lines are ordered by the id, I could think of an effective solution. If not, you have to build some index structure first- and that is essentially what databases do. So then, you should use one.

Comment: The lines are not ordered in input files. The number of line can be about million

Comment: @Jarosław Jaryszew  Thank you, Do you mean I should convert files to sqlite db, merge logs, and result to text file again. Would it be faster and memory safer? And could it be divided (optimazed by time) using much thwn one processor?

Comment: You can str1 as the dict key directly; it would seem to take about 170 MB with one million 80-byte keys and int values.

Comment: @Janne Karila, thank you, yes, but it might grow to much in case of increasing lines to 10 or 100 million - and it could happen in future (I mean numbers of lines)

Comment: @alex.egorov - this would be slower then processing everything in memory but unless you leak some objects it should set ceiling on memory usage. Multithreading should help . Maybe a thread for each of input files?

Answer (score 0):

The hashes provided with python are designed to be cryptographically strong, which means, in simple terms, that they're processor intensive.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575787/looking-for-a-fast-hash-function) for other options if you do decide to go with the script solution.

Comment: The built-in `hash()` function is fast. You are thinking about the functions in `hashlib`.