# Fast Hash function in PHP without caring about security

Tags: hash, md5

I am looking for a fast hash functions that I will use internally in my webapp. It does not need to be secure (e.g. I do not care if a possible attacker could find a message with the same hash).

It just needs to be fast and obviously collision resistant. For now it seems that MD5 would be the best approach (See the stackoverflow Thread [Is calculating an MD5 hash less CPU intensive than SHA family functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722943/is-calculating-an-md5-hash-less-cpu-intensive-than-sha-1-or-sha-2)).
Or has anyrone ran into a similiar issue and knows of a better hash algorithm?

**Update**

Sorry, I guess I should have looked more carefully: [Looking for a fast hash-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575787/looking-for-a-fast-hash-function)

Comment: Please describe in more details for which purpose you need the hash function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for a fast hash-function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575787/looking-for-a-fast-hash-function)

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for hash function that's fast and low collision. Murmur3 hash would be the way to go. You can obtain a c++ copy [here](https://code.google.com/p/smhasher/source/browse/#svn/branches/chandlerc_dev%253Fstate%253Dclosed).

One of many php implementation [here](https://github.com/taskaz/labloom/blob/master/murmur3.php).

Review:
http://www.strchr.com/hash_functions